# Confusing clang error attempting to instantiate std::thread with a pointer

Tags: c++11, clang++

While looking at [Thread and interfaces C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31042566/1204143), I noticed something a little strange with my Clang.

I have `c++ --version` output of

```
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Compiling the following

```
#include <thread>

class Foo {
public:
    void operator()() { }
};

int main() {
    Foo *foo = new Foo();
    std::thread t(foo);
    t.join();
    delete foo;
}
```

with `c++ thread.cpp` yields the following sensible error:

```
In file included from thread.cpp:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:369:5: error: called object type 'Foo *' is not a function or
      function pointer
    (*__p)();
    ^~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:377:42: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::__thread_proxy<Foo *>' requested here
    int __ec = pthread_create(&__t_, 0, &__thread_proxy<_Fp>, __p.get());
                                         ^
thread.cpp:10:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::thread::thread<Foo *>' requested here
    std::thread t(foo);
                ^
1 error generated.
```

Total sense - `Foo *` isn't a function pointer.

But, compiling it with `c++ -std=c++11 thread.cpp` gives this cryptic error:

```
In file included from thread.cpp:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:332:5: error: attempt to use a deleted function
    __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<0>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:342:5: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::__thread_execute<Foo *>' requested here
    __thread_execute(*__p, _Index());
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:354:42: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<Foo *> >' requested here
    int __ec = pthread_create(&__t_, 0, &__thread_proxy<_Gp>, __p.get());
                                         ^
thread.cpp:10:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::thread::thread<Foo *&, void>' requested here
    std::thread t(foo);
                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:1027:5: note: '~__nat' has been explicitly marked
      deleted here
    ~__nat() = delete;
    ^
1 error generated.
```

What's causing this weird error message about a deleted destructor? Should I consider it a bug in Clang to have such an odd message?

Answer (score 0):

Your actual error message is the same in the two cases: whatever template is used to implement std::thread, it cannot be specialized for Foo*.
`~__nat() = delete;` is only a random difference between the old and new standard, one of the uninteresting things that fail because of the type error.